# Is there any windows 8.1 in my system with my ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04

I had successfully installed ubuntu 14.04 with Windows 8.1. But due to some problem, I had to re-install ubuntu. I put ubuntu bootable USB in system and selected "erase ubuntu ans re-install ubuntu". Then my ubuntu problem got solved but now it is not showing windows 8.1 in start-up. I want to check if I had removed my windows completely?

Here is my 500GB hard disk output with lsblk command:

> ```
> NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
> sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
> ├─sda1   8:1    0 461.9G  0 part /
> ├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
> └─sda5   8:5    0   3.9G  0 part [SWAP]
> sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
> ```

Please check and tell is there windows on my any partitions of hard-disk?

Comment: Unfortunately you deleted Windows. The "Erase" option erases everything. You should select "Something Else".

Comment: @Danatela what should I do now?

Comment: Can you tell me procedure for that? I am a noob. I am not an expert.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you have deleted your Windows partition.

[Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) would help you to recover some of your datas.

Comment: what should I do now?